# How can I add field in a certain collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to know how to add a field in a certain user uid [image]

So I'd like to add another field like Address for the currentUser "Rowan Whitethorn". How can I do this?

Currently, i could add another field but it creates another documents.

const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid);

```
async function addAddress() {
   const res = await userRef.set({
       'Address' : 'Ayala'
   }, { merge : true});
}
```

Comment: In general you update the record with the field you want to add. The collection documents don't need to have the same fields in them. So if you want it in all of the documents in the collection, you will need to update all the documents adding the field

Answer (score 2):

Firestore documentation describes a feature "merge", where you would typically create a new doc with using ".set", but then pass a parameter "merge" which tells firebase not to overwrite your doc data, in your case it would be something like:

```
const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(doc_id);

const res = await userRef.set({
    'some_new_field': 'value'
}, { merge: true });
```

Here's the link for their documentation, you will find a similar example under "merge": https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: so in the firestore, it'll add another field like address in that uid with no problems, right?